# How to select current cell with JavaScript in Jupyter?

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook cell containing JavaScript code, and I would like the code to select this particular cell. Unfortunately, the behavior of `get_selected_cell` depends on whether I execute the cell in place, or execute and select the cell below.

**Example:**

```
%%javascript
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
console.log(Jupyter.notebook.find_cell_index(cell));
```

When executing this cell, the console output will be different whether I execute with `Ctrl+Enter` or `Shift+Enter`. In one case it logs the index of the cell that contains the JavaScript code, in the other the index of the cell below.

Is there a way to select the cell I want?

Comment: `selected_cell` means the one that is selected in the UI. Inside Javascript added to the output area of a cell, `this` is the output area. I can't currently find a way back from that to the cell it belongs to, though.

Comment: @ThomasK thanks, I guess it's not possible then...

Comment: I suspect it probably is possible with some convoluted JS hackery, but I don't know how. Feel free to open a feature request on the [notebook repo](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) for an official way to reference the cell from JS output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Javascript will have a handle on the OutputArea applying the Javascript, but not one all the way to the cell (in general, output areas can be used without cells or notebooks). You can find the cell by identifying the parent `.cell` element, and then getting the cell corresponding to that element:

```
%%javascript
var output_area = this;
// find my cell element
var cell_element = output_area.element.parents('.cell');
// which cell is it?
var cell_idx = Jupyter.notebook.get_cell_elements().index(cell_element);
// get the cell object
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_cell(cell_idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of executing javascript with `display(HTML("javascript code"))`, `this` will return the Window object.

So you should use `display(Javascript("javascript code"))` to get the current cells' output_area.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a jupyter lab widget, you can get the cell index by iterating the `widget` array. This is what jupyter lab internally does ([source](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/5755ea86fef3fdbba10cd05b23703b9d60b53226/packages/notebook/src/widget.ts#L1803)).

```
const cellIndex = ArrayExt.findFirstIndex(
  notebook.content.widgets,
  widget => widget.node === this.originalCell.node
);
```

Then you can assign the new active cell by changing the `activeCellIndex` property of the notebook widget:

```
notebook.content.activeCellIndex = cellIndex;
```

Comment: I've been unable to find a way to access the `notebook` object from a Jupyter widget the way you illustrate. Could you provide a more complete sample please?